# NodeJs: JSON Array/Object merging not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

Having an issue with merging nested JSON Array objects.

```
var o1 = {
    "customerId": "ABC",        
    "questions": [
        {
        "status": 2,
        "isBookmarked": 0,
        "questionId": 1 
        }
      ]      
    }
   

 var o2 = {
  "customerId": "ABC",    
  "questions": [
      {
      "status": 1,
      "isBookmarked": 1,
      "questionId": 2    
      },
      {
      "status": 1,
      "isBookmarked": 1,
      "questionId": 3    
      }
    ]   
  }
```

The question array needs to merge together. If the same question is found in both objects then it should take 2 object values (o2 - object).

I tried to do it like this:

```
const o3 = Object.assign({}, o1, o2);
```

Here is the link to reproduce - https://jsfiddle.net/y97afosd/

Expected output -

```
{
  "customerId": "ABC",    
  "questions": [
            {
        "status": 2,
        "isBookmarked": 0,
        "questionId": 1 
      },
      {
      "status": 1,
      "isBookmarked": 1,
      "questionId": 2    
      },
      {
      "status": 1,
      "isBookmarked": 1,
      "questionId": 3    
      }
    ]   
  }
```

Can someone help with it?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y97afosd/

Comment: Thanks for editing the question! Please prefer [on-site Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) to off-site things like jsFiddle. When you make your reproducible example off-site, it's too easy to leave things out of the question, and your whole question has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt didn't work because `o2`'s `questions` array completely replaces `o1`'s.

Instead, **if** there were no duplicates you could use spread to copy the other object properties and to append `o2`'s questions to the ones from `o1`:

```
const o3 = {
    ...o1,
    ...o2,
    questions: [...o1.questions, ...o2.questions]
};
```

Or if you wanted to avoid spread syntax for some reason, you could use `Object.assign` and `Array.prototype.concat`:

```
const o4 = Object.assign({}, o1, o2, {
    questions: o1.questions.concat(o2.questions)
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const o1 = {
    "customerId": "ABC",
    "questions": [
        {
            "status": 2,
            "isBookmarked": 0,
            "questionId": 1
        }
    ]
};

const o2 = {
    "customerId": "ABC",
    "questions": [
        {
            "status": 1,
            "isBookmarked": 1,
            "questionId": 2
        },
        {
            "status": 1,
            "isBookmarked": 1,
            "questionId": 3
        }
    ]
};

const o3 = {
    ...o1,
    ...o2,
    questions: [...o1.questions, ...o2.questions]
};
console.log(o3);

// Or with `Object.assign`:

const o4 = Object.assign({}, o1, o2, {
    questions: o1.questions.concat(o2.questions)
});
console.log(o4);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note, though, that `Object.assign` (even the one in your question) **is** multiple loops. They just aren't in *your* code. :-)

But you've said there may be duplicates (I'm assuming based on `questionId`) and that the ones from `o1` should win over the ones from `o2`. That's *slightly* more complicated, but not that much:

```
const o3 = {
    ...o1,
    ...o2,
    questions: [...new Map([
        ...o2.questions.map(q => [q.questionId, q]),    // Note o2 first...
        ...o1.questions.map(q => [q.questionId, q]),    // ...so duplicates overwrite
    ]).values()]
};
```

Instead of four loops (two copying the objects, two copying the arrays), we now have eight I think (two copying the objects, two mapping the arrays, two copying the arrays, one building the Map, and one extracting the Map's values) plus some indexed lookups when building the `Map`.

Live Example:

```js
const o1 = {
    "customerId": "ABC",
    "questions": [
        {
            "status": 2,
            "isBookmarked": 0,
            "questionId": 1
        },
        { // Duplicated below with different status
            "status": 1,
            "isBookmarked": 0,
            "questionId": 4
        }

    ]
};

const o2 = {
    "customerId": "ABC",
    "questions": [
        {
            "status": 1,
            "isBookmarked": 1,
            "questionId": 2
        },
        { // Duplicated above with different status
            "status": 2,
            "isBookmarked": 0,
            "questionId": 4
        },
        {
            "status": 1,
            "isBookmarked": 1,
            "questionId": 3
        }
    ]
};

const o3 = {
    ...o1,
    ...o2,
    questions: [...new Map([
        ...o2.questions.map(q => [q.questionId, q]),    // Note o2 first...
        ...o1.questions.map(q => [q.questionId, q]),    // ...so duplicates overwrite
    ]).values()]
};
console.log(o3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If that's too many, we can keep it to four (plus some indexed lookups in the `Set`):

```
const o3 = {
    ...o1,
    ...o2,
    questions: []
};
const seen = new Set();
for (const q of o1.questions) {
    o3.questions.push(q);
    seen.add(q.questionId);
}
for (const q of o2.questions) {
    if (!seen.has(q.questionId)) {
        o3.questions.push(q);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const o1 = {
    "customerId": "ABC",
    "questions": [
        {
            "status": 2,
            "isBookmarked": 0,
            "questionId": 1
        },
        { // Duplicated below with different status
            "status": 1,
            "isBookmarked": 0,
            "questionId": 4
        }

    ]
};

const o2 = {
    "customerId": "ABC",
    "questions": [
        {
            "status": 1,
            "isBookmarked": 1,
            "questionId": 2
        },
        { // Duplicated above with different status
            "status": 2,
            "isBookmarked": 0,
            "questionId": 4
        },
        {
            "status": 1,
            "isBookmarked": 1,
            "questionId": 3
        }
    ]
};

const o3 = {
    ...o1,
    ...o2,
    questions: []
};
const seen = new Set();
for (const q of o1.questions) {
    o3.questions.push(q);
    seen.add(q.questionId);
}
for (const q of o2.questions) {
    if (!seen.has(q.questionId)) {
        o3.questions.push(q);
    }
}
console.log(o3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: there may be a duplicate question and in that case, it should pick up from array 1 (o1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce method to solve your problem

```js
var o1 = {
    "customerId": "ABC",        
    "questions": [
        {
        "status": 2,
        "isBookmarked": 0,
        "questionId": 1 
        }
      ]      
    }
   

 var o2 = {
  "customerId": "ABC",    
  "questions": [
      {
      "status": 1,
      "isBookmarked": 1,
      "questionId": 2    
      },
      {
      "status": 1,
      "isBookmarked": 1,
      "questionId": 3    
      }
    ]   
  }
  
  const o3 =  o2.questions.reduce((arr, item) => {
    arr.questions.push(item);
    return arr;    
}, o1);
console.log(o3);
```

Comment: You *can* shoehorn any array operation into a `reduce` call, but you usually shouldn't. `reduce` is great in functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions. Outside of that niche context, it's just an overcomplicated loop. Also note that the OP says that in cases of duplication, `o1`'s question should be kept, but this doesn't do that. It also modifies `o1.questions`, which would be a big no-no in functional programming (and probably isn't ideal here either, but the OP didn't say either way).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://github.com/TehShrike/deepmerge

```
import deepmerge = require('deepmerge');
import util = require('util');

const x = {
  foo: { bar: 3 },
  array: [
    {
      does: 'work',
      too: [1, 2, 3],
    },
  ],
};

const y = {
  foo: { baz: 4 },
  quux: 5,
  array: [
    {
      does: 'work',
      too: [4, 5, 6],
    },
    {
      really: 'yes',
    },
  ],
};

console.log(util.inspect(deepmerge(x, y), false, null, true));
```

Output:

```
{
  foo: { bar: 3, baz: 4 },
  array: [
    { does: 'work', too: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
    { does: 'work', too: [ 4, 5, 6 ] },
    { really: 'yes' }
  ],
  quux: 5
}
```

Usage with array of any:

```
map.reduce((x, y) => deepmerge(x, y));
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it's working as intended, the issue is you're trying to merge object with the same exact properties, therefore the properties inside the second object are overriding the properties in the first.

Try adding other, different properties to both objects and you'll see the method is actually working.

Comment: No, it isn't working as intended. The OP wants the two `questions` arrays *merged*. What they're doing only keeps `o2`'s, throwing away `o1`'s.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant that Object.assign is working as intended, as in if you have objects with the same properties, the second will override the first.